# Operate one list (CList) by two threads, will the iterator be invalid?

Tags: c++, multithreading

In my work, I use a list(CList) to store records. In order to improve the performance, I use two threads to modify this list separately. The main thread only add new record to the head, and the worker thread will search the list to find some records, also the worker thread can remove records from the tail. In my case, I have concern on the iterators (POSITION). For example, the worker thread find a record and save its POSITION, But before the worker thread do following work on the found record, the main thread may insert some new records at the head. So my question is that at this time, whether the found record's POSITION is still valid? Can I use the POSITION to get my expected origin record data? I don't want to lock the list, I want the list can be changed by the two threads.
Further more, can the add operation by main thread and delete operation by worker thread occur at same time?
If my design is not proper, what method should I use?
Thanks.

Comment: why don't you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://$SITEURL$/help/mcve) to better visualize the problem?